# How to merge a specific column with each column of a dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe, merge, multiple-columns

Let's say I have this df (my original dataframe is so much bigger)

```
df = data.frame(ID = c(1,2,2,3,4,5,5),
                T = c(1,1,2,1,2,1,2),
                product_1 = c('A','A','B','C','A','C','D'),
                product_2 = c('C','A','B','A','B','E','C'),

                )
```

I wish to have the following output

`````
  ID   product_1_T1 product_1_T2 product_2_T1 product_2_T2
1  1            A         <NA>            C         <NA>
2  2            A            B            A            B
3  3            C         <NA>            A         <NA>
4  4         <NA>            A         <NA>            B
5  5            C            D            E            C
> 
````
`````

Answer (score 1):

With `pivot_wider`:

```r
library(tidyr)
pivot_wider(df, names_from = 'T', values_from = product_1:product_2, names_prefix = "T")

# A tibble: 5 × 5
     ID product_1_T1 product_1_T2 product_2_T1 product_2_T2
  <dbl> <chr>        <chr>        <chr>        <chr>       
1     1 A            NA           C            NA          
2     2 A            B            A            B           
3     3 C            NA           A            NA          
4     4 NA           A            NA           B           
5     5 C            D            E            C
```